# Is there a way that I could see the codes behind a visual and non-visual component?

Tags: delphi, components

I was just wondering if there is a way that I could go down to the codes of a component (visual or non-visual)? It would be a great relief for a coder to understand how a component behaves in the back-end. Perhaps, a coder could do some changes or add complementary codes to fit its requirement.

Comment: Assuming your Delphi version comes with source, set the compiler option `Use debug .dcus` and you will then be able to use the debugger to trace into the implementing code of a component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Delphi includes the source code then its easy.

Switch to the unit of the form that includes the component

[image]

Go to the declaration of the component, right-click on the the component's type and the click on `Find Declaration`

[image]

And there you go, the component's code.

[image]

Now you can `Find Declaration` on the ancestor, in this case `TCustomPanel` and see how the ancestor is made.

There are many resources explaining how they all fit together and many on how to create components. Once you understand classes and this whole Object Orientated thing then you will find it easier.

I started creating components long ago and by looking at the source code of other components I learned so much. I still do.

Comment: Indeed, studying the RTL and VCL units is a great way to learn. Just a note: sometimes (actually, far too often), the "Find declaration" command doesn't work. Then you might try to Ctrl+click the identifier instead. If that doesn't work either, you can open the unit manually and search for `TPanel = class(` in it.

Comment: To all of you. Thank you so much! This would be a great help for us new coders.